# Alternative repository for QGIS 2.0 plugins?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, repository

Is there any alternative to the official repository for plugins of QGIS 2.0?

I found a source which refers to OpenGeo Explorer
For more info:
http://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/static/docs/intro.html

Answer (score 3):

For what reason do you need another repository?
In theory anyone can set up a private repo for QGIS, which can then be added via the settings in the plugin-downloader.

You can find a lot of alternative on this [wikipage](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Python_Plugin_Repositories), but many of the other repos and plugins are old/deprecated and not maintained anymore or even integrated into the main QGIS hub.

Comment: You said " In theory anyone can set up a private repo for QGIS". Exactly for that reason I asked if there is another repository. As an example I will bring Ubuntu which has many different repositories.

Comment: To my knowledge: No, there is no existing alternative plugin repo with working QGIS 2.0 plugins.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to install from other repositories was more important a few versions ago. Since version 1.7 (or so?) the community has made an effort to have all plugins installed through the official repositories. I don't know of any independent repositories anymore, and there was a major change in QGIS 2.0 requiring all plugins to be adapted to the new PyQGIS API, so if you do come across any independent repositories, they are almost definitely outdated. Most plugin developers are submitting their plugins for inclusion in the official repository. Since the official repository can include "experimental" plugins (i.e., what might also be called "testing" or "unstable"), the barrier to entry is pretty low, and there is little reason why someone would choose to set up an independent repository anymore.

Note that if you happen to come across a plugin not in a repository (e.g. on GitHub), you can "install" the plugin by just copying the code to a subfolder of  ~/.qgis2/python/plugins. You could also attempt to do this with any pre-2.0 plugins you find and adapt them yourself to the new API, although it's probably worth reaching out to the developer to find out if they are already working on it, or if they feel it has been superseded by newer plugins or by features integrated in QGIS core.

Comment: Nevertheless it is a valuable question if this centralization is actually beneficial if the number of QGIS users and plugins increases even further. Like if the plugin hub suffers from some overload-breakdown...

Comment: @Curlew that is a good point. I will raise it with the guys who run the site.

Answer (score 1):

Boundless Geo maintains a repository for plugins that they have created:
https://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/

It has some useful tools that are not in the official repository.